# How to pick fresh record when cron starts the job

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, cron

I want to select and use ONLY new records that have been inserted between a Cron job runs and the next run. In this sense I don't repeat any data or records that I worked on earlier.

From the select statement below, please someone direct me, thank you.

```
// select statement should pick fresh records only after the first cron

$sql = "SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); // fetch data
$name = $resultarr['name'];
$amount = $resultarr['amount'];
$transaction_id = $resultarr['trans_id'];
$date = $resultarr['time_paid'];
```

This is important because the data will be used to send an SMS and I don't want to send an SMS twice to someone.

Kindly, anyone?

Comment: You probably need to consider adding " WHERE time_paid > " & time of cron job completion to the `$sql` variable...

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column called as notification_sent in your table. 
Now on when each cron  runs add a where clause and only get data where notification_sent is set to 0, somewhat like below:

```
SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer where notification_sent = 0;
```

Once you get the data send the email notification to those user and update the flag to notification_sent as 1.

This way next time you will not repeat it to send them again.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer WHERE notification_sent = 0" ? I actually don't get you.

Comment: Yes, what I am saying is add a new column in your table called as notification_sent and default it to 0. Now when you send notification update flag to 1.

Comment: you need to "flag" the records that you've sent notifications for, so when cron triggers you can select only those rows that haven't been "flagged" (if any). that's what @chandresh_cool is telling you.

Comment: @OliverMaksimovic bang on that is what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: @BobMyles you just need to write an update sql, when you send the notification after sending if the notification is sent write an update sql that sets flag to 1.

Comment: @OliverMaksimovic // Select                                                                                                                               $sql = "SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer WHERE notification = '0';


            $sq = UPDATE customer SET notification = '1' WHERE  notification = '0';
            $retval = mysql_query($sq, $conn);  
you mean like this?

Answer (score 0):

Add new column status and sent_at in that table .
after running cron job you can update status and sent_at

SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer where status=0;

if you want to run cron job at regular interval you can use sent_at column in where condition.

SELECT name,amount, trans_id, msisdn, time_paid FROM customer where status=0 and sent_at!=?;

after success of cron you can use

update table set status=1 where trans_id in (trans_id1,trans_id2 .. trans_idn
)

condition according to your requirement

Comment: you have all the selected trans_id.after cron job you can update like update table set  status=1 where id in (trans_id1,trans_id2) like this.